# Append only 4 divs and the remaining divs in another section

Tags: jquery, html, append, detach

Say there is a section with 12 divs. I'm trying to append 4 divs at a time into into a new section (container). So there will be 4 divs appended in the first section, then 4 divs appended to a different second section, then 4 divs to a third section, and so on.

Beginner wordpress/jQuery coder here; I would greatly appreciate explanations :) Open to other approaches but I'd like to have these 3 functions:

1) some counting mechanism so that a section holds only up to 4 divs

2) if there are more than 4 divs (say 6) a new section created to house the remaining 2

3) adding the divs that have not already been added.

Starting with 12 divs in a section:

```
  <section>
      <div> 1 </div>
      <div> 2 </div>
      <div> 3 </div>
      <div> 4 </div>
      <div> 5 </div>
      <div> 6 </div>
      <div> 7 </div>
      <div> 8 </div>
      <div> 9 </div>
      <div> 10 </div>
      <div> 11 </div>
      <div> 12 </div>
  </section>
```

after the JQuery, I'd like the divs appended to be organized as:

```
 <section id="FirstSection">
      <div> 1 </div>
      <div> 2 </div>
      <div> 3 </div>
      <div> 4 </div>
  </section>
  <section id="SecondSection">
      <div> 5 </div>
      <div> 6 </div>
      <div> 7 </div>
      <div> 8 </div>
  </section>
  <section id="ThirdSection">
      <div> 9 </div>
      <div> 10 </div>
      <div> 11 </div>
      <div> 12 </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Generally, Stack Overflow appreciates when people show some effort into solving a problem on the part of the asker. See [ask] for example, where the first section is titled "Search, and research".

Comment: Oh I see.. I'll add some examples I'd experimented with in future questions. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code works for you. I also made a demo [here](https://codepen.io/iLtc/pen/GRKXZgj).

```
<section>
    <div> 1 </div>
    <div> 2 </div>
    <div> 3 </div>
    <div> 4 </div>
    <div> 5 </div>
    <div> 6 </div>
    <div> 7 </div>
    <div> 8 </div>
    <div> 9 </div>
    <div> 10 </div>
    <div> 11 </div>
    <div> 12 </div>
</section>
<div id="main"></div>
<script>
    var div_count = 0;
    var section_count = 0;

$('div[id!="main"]').each(function () {
  if ($("#section-"+section_count).length == 0) {
    $('#main').append('<section id="section-'+section_count+'"></section>');
  }

  $("#section-"+section_count)[0].append($(this).html());
  $(this).remove();

  div_count += 1;

  if (div_count > 3) {
    div_count = 0;
    section_count += 1;
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Note that you can provide a runnable demo here on Stack Overflow using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so that people don't have to navigate to another site.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I used this code several times. I had trouble getting the entire div (not just the content inside the div) and found using just $("#section-"+section_count).append(this); and removing $(this).remove(); works as well. Thank you again!